# How to make redirects in WP?

Tags: html, wordpress, redirect

I'm very confused about what I should use to redirect my pages.
So far I did this:

```
<a class="navbar-brand" href="<?= esc_url(home_url('/')) ?>">
                    <img class="nav-logo" src="<?php echo $img1; ?>" alt="Logo Canoa, flèche blanche sur fond vert">
</a>
<li class="nav-item">
  <a class="underline nav-link media-screen-nav" href="chatbot-lilou">Chatbot Lilou</a>
</li>
<li class="nav-item">
  <a class="underline nav-link media-screen-nav" href="contact-demo">Contact & Démo</a>
</li>
```

The redirects work but I realize when I put my mouse on my links, in the bottom left and corner of my screen it shows : **localhost/canoaGuide/NameOfActualPage/WhatsWrittenInHref**

In this example with the code below Im on chatbot-lilou page and I want to go in Contact & Demo, it shows : **localhost/siteweb/chatbot-lilou/contact-demo** . I didn't pay attention before because it was working but I realize now that it's weird and probably not the good way on wordpress.

Another example that confirms my feeling I'm doing something wrong it's when I redirect between my articles for my blog.
For example, I want to check all the articles in the coffee category, it works but starting from here all my next clic will add the href content, like this :
**localhost/siteweb/category/coffee/chatbot-lilou/chatbot-lilou**

Comment: Try using a base tag in the head section of your document. I  am not sure but I think `<base href="/">` it will solve this.

Comment: I used <base href="/siteweb/"> and it actually works, I didnt know the base tag, thank you very much.